# AS3: Embedding characters

Tags: actionscript-3, text, embedded-fonts

I having some trouble with TextFields and caracter embedding. As I have understood, the way to embed character in Flash, is to have a TextField in a movieclip that is exported to actionscript via some classname. Then have the TextField embed the characters.

But when i try to use that TextField in my project, I cannot auto resize the field any longer!? Is there a better way to embed charactes? or am I missing some unknow attribute? (and yes i have tried `TextField.autoSize = "left" (or "center" or "right")`).

The TextField is configured like this in Flash CS4:
Properties:
http://screencast.com/t/0VB6KnNO6G
Library implementation:
http://screencast.com/t/w3yQLqit0veI

And I embed the MovieClip containing the TextField like this:

```
protected var tabname:MovieClip = new Text(); // The property on the object
```

Adding the text and setting its Settings:

```
var txt:TextField = tabname.txt;

        if( !contains(tabname) )
        {
            addChild(tabname);

            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                format.bold = true;
                format.font = "Arial";
                format.size = 12;
                format.align = "left";

            var dropShadow = new DropShadowFilter(0);
                dropShadow.color = 0xFFFFFF;
                dropShadow.strength = 2;
                dropShadow.blurX = dropShadow.blurY = 5;
                dropShadow.alpha = .7;

            txt.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
            txt.multiline = tabname.wordWrap = false;
            txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            txt.defaultTextFormat = format;
            txt.filters = [dropShadow];
            txt.mouseEnabled = false;
            txt.x = 10;
        }

        txt.text = value;
        txt.y = Math.ceil((tabmask.height - txt.height) /2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To embed fonts, don't rely on wrapping them in MovieClips in the library. They should be embedded correctly as Fonts. I have included some basic steps below for embedding fonts, then an example for your particular situation:

1 - Make the textfield Dynamic and click the Embed.. button

[image]

2 - Name the font with something meaningful (like the fonts name) and tick the character sets you will be using (usually I select caps, lowercase, numbers and punctuation). Also note the Style is 'Bold', you will need to embed a font set for each style. So if you want to use Bold and Regular, you need to embed 2 fonts.

[image]

3 - If you plan on adding textfields dynamically through ActionScript, goto the ActionScript tab and add a class for it (again, use a meaningful name)

[image]

4 - Finally click ok, and away you go. I have setup an example, using these steps, and the auto size method, you can see the results below

[image]

Comment: Hey thanx. That cleared up a thing or two for me, but im not sure how you got to embed charaters on the font. I remind you I'm using CS4.

Comment: A textfield in CS4 still has the embed button, just click on the textfield then goto it's properties. Hopefully my answer has helped

Comment: hm ok... I just understood, that I didn't need to include the text field in a movieclip, to embed characters (not the font - characters). But I guess that isn't the case? or what?

Comment: If you use the above steps, you will be fine. Try doing just the above, for a simple test case, then start to add extra functionality

Comment: well in your steps you assume I have a text field on the stage, which i don't. I load it in dynamically. Thats why i have it in my library in a MovieClip.

Comment: That's fine, but you don't need to use a MovieClip. Right click in the library, then click New Font, then follow the rest of the steps and it will be fine

Answer (score 1):

In Flash, you can click the [Embed...] button below the TextField's character properties. In the window that you get then, you can specify which characters you want embedded in your textfield.

There's a lot more to say about font embedding but this is the simple story. Flash CS5 added TLF TextFields but I don't think you were referring to those, right?

The autoSize property really has nothing to do with font embedding but I guess your TextField is not Dynamic when you cannot auto resize it?

Are you using CS5 or CS4 or earlier by the way?

Comment: Im using CS4, but i do know the way to embed characters from flash. But the textfield does not resize after I added the Moieclip that contains the textfield. But the TextField IS Dynamic. I can't seem to change the font-weight either.... pretty annoying.

Comment: OK I'm sorry for misunderstanding your question. One thing strikes me in your code: the line `txt.multiline = tabname.wordWrap = false;` because wordWrap is not a property of a MovieClip but of a TextField so that should read `txt.wordWrap`.  Also, in the code you're not actually using an embedded font, am I right? So the whole embedding thing may be irrelevant?