# FLASH AS3 Icelandic characters not showing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi I am trying to use Icelandic characters in AS3 for a flash banner.

I can write most of them in the AS3 frame (not Ð) but when I start the banner the Icelandic characters are missing pls help meh :)

Comment: you need to embed the font http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626386/as3-embedding-characters

Comment: Thank you Ronnie I just needed to ad the characters in the embed font selection you just made my day :)

Comment: Delete your question please, it's a duplicate

Comment: @CreativeMagic I think this question is still useful and shouldn't be deleted. People Googling about embedding Icelandic characters will end up here much quicker than they would the 'duplicate' question.